# How to create substring from string at specific fixed length

Tags: java, string, substring

I have `java String` with more than 160 character, on that i want to `create substring` form that string for first 150 character.

I have google it for that but what i got is for make substring at special character.

Please show me possible way for do this..

Comment: `substring()` method. Very straightforward. `s.substring(0, 150)`; In the future, look into the javadocs for the class in question and see if there's a method there that does what you need.

Comment: Does `String.substring(0, 150)` not work?

Comment: Very first hit on Google: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm @Kon answer is spot on unless you meant something else.

Comment: I actually can't understand how someone with 1745 StackOverflow reputation is unable to use Google to find out how to create a substring in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[String#substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) is what you need.

```
String mySubString = myString.substring(0, 150);
```